# how to run multiples NSRegularExpression once

Tags: swift, regex, nsregularexpression

I have a bunch of `NSRegularExpression` and I want to run it once. Anyone knows how to do it ?

For the moment I do it in a `.forEach`, for performance reasons I do not think this is the best idea

Each `NSRegularExpression` needs to match a different pattern, after the matching I need to deal with each different kind of match. As example if I match with the first regex in my array I need to make something different from the second etc...

```
let test: String = "Stuff"
let range: NSRange = // a range

var regexes = [NSRegularExpression] = // all of my regexes
regexes.forEach { $0.matches(in: text, options: [], range: range) }
```

Thanks for you help

Comment: Without showing any of your NSRegularExpressions, the array or your current code it would be difficult to answer this..
Please edit the question to include your code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: From what I have seen in Apple document regarding to `NSRegularExpression`, it seems that you won't be able to do it. However, how about doing all of matching stuffs concurrency with `GCD`?

Comment: Thanks for your answers guys, I've update the answer @Theo

Comment: @RyanB it can nice yeah

Comment: "f I match with the first regex in my array I need to make something different from the second" Define different? What kind of operation do you want to do? Could you give a more explicit example?

Comment: @Larme For each regex I'll apply different text attributes to a label

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to evaluate several regular expressions as one if you concatenate them using capture groups and an **OR** expressions.

If you want to search for: `language`, `Objective-C` and `Swift` strings you should use a pattern like this: `(language)|(Objective-C)|(Swift)`.  Each capture group has an order number, so if `language` is found in the source string the match object  provides the index number.

You can used the code in this playground sample:

```
import Foundation

let sourceString: String = "Swift is a great language to program, but don't forget Objective-C."
let expresions = [ "language",     // Expression 0
                   "Objective-C",  // Expression 1
                   "Swift"         // Expression 2
                 ]
let pattern = expresions
                .map { "(\($0))" }
                .joined(separator: "|") // pattern is defined as : (language)|(Objective-C)|(Swift)

let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [])
let matches = regex?.matches(in: sourceString, options: [],
                         range: NSRange(location: 0, length: sourceString.utf16.count))
let results = matches?.map({ (match) -> (Int, String) in // Array of type (Int: String) which
                                                         // represents index of expression and
                                                         // string capture
    let index = (1...match.numberOfRanges-1) // Go through all ranges to test which one was used
                 .map{ Range(match.range(at: $0), in: sourceString) != nil ? $0 : nil }
                 .compactMap { $0 }.first! // Previous map return array with nils and just one Int
                                           // with the correct position, lets apply compactMap to
                                           // get just this number

    let foundString = String(sourceString[Range(match.range(at: 0), in: sourceString)!])
    let position = match.range(at: 0).location
    let niceReponse = "\(foundString) [position: \(position)]"
    return (index - 1, niceReponse) // Let's substract 1 to index in order to match  zero based array index
})

print("Matches: \(results?.count ?? 0)\n")
results?.forEach({ result in
    print("Group \(result.0): \(result.1)")
})
```

If you run it the result is:

```
How many matches: 3

Expression 2: Swift [position: 0]
Expression 0: language [position: 17]
Expression 1: Objective-C [position: 55]
```

I hope I understood correctly your question and this code helps you.